SQL Server 2008/2019 Connection Issue
Connection could not be established.
Not able to connect and execute queries from PHP.
I'm getting this...

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => HY000 [SQLSTATE] => HY000 [1] => -2146893042 [code] => -2146893042 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HY000 [SQLSTATE] => HY000 [1] => -2146893042 [code] => -2146893042 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context ) [2] => Array ( [0] => HY000 [SQLSTATE] => HY000 [1] => -2146893042 [code] => -2146893042 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: No credentials are available in the security package ) [3] => Array ( [0] => HY000 [SQLSTATE] => HY000 [1] => -2146893042 [code] => -2146893042 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context ) )

Here's my code. I searched, but couldn't find any solution.
<?php


/* $serverName = "PANDORAS-BOX\EXP_2008R2"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433) */
$serverName = "Server, port"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXX", "UID"=>"XX", "PWD"=>"XX","Trusted Connection"=>"yes");
$connectionInfo = [
    'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
];
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn == True) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "Select Account_Id,Account_No From Savings_Account Where IPKS Is Null";
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt) ) {
              print json_encode($row);
        }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>


Choose one authentication mechanism. "Trusted Connection"=>"yes" means to use the Windows authentication token of the currently running process, which seems to be the source of your error message. If you wish to use SQL Login (username+password based) authentication with "UID"=>"XX", "PWD"=>"XX" then remove "Trusted Connection"=>"yes" from the connection properties.

Aside... are you actually still using SQL Server 2008? You should have migrated away from that unsupported version many years ago.

I've removed it. now I'm getting this...
Connection established.
Fatal error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08004 [SQLSTATE] => 08004 [1] => 916 [code] => 916 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The server principal "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" is not able to access the database "CBS" under the current security context. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The server principal "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" is not able to access the database "XXX" under the current security context. ) ) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\resolute\php\connection.php on line 19

The point is, I have granted all necessary access for the database to the user I am using. Still getting this error. it blows my brain, what to do?

I'm using 2019 Developer Edition.

The server principal "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" is not able to access the database "XXX" under the current security context. It's still trying to use Windows authentication, @Captain-Sam. Did you remove "Trusted Connection"=>"yes" only to do something else that means Windows authentication, like say removing the UID and PWD properties as well?

I've removed trusted connection .
here's my code...

"CBS", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"XXX");
$connectionInfo = [
    'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
];
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn == True) {
     echo "Connection established.";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT Id FROM [CBS].[dbo].[ERROR_Log]";

$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($res === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
I get that error only when I run that selection query.

So, you're setting $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CBS", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"XXX"); and then immediately replacing it with $connectionInfo = [ 'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8', ];?
